# Redirect multiple domains to one domain (with or without www before)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, http-status-code-301, multiple-domains

I have about 18 domains that need to be redirected to a new one. It has to work both with or without www prepended.

I've tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

That gives me a redirect loop (and only works with www before, i think?).

Comment: Because the `[OR]` at the end of each domain was not in your answer, and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain4.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain5.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This will redirect all your 18 domains to your new single domain `www.newdomain.com`.

---

Otherwise you can use following code to redirect each domain if they are on separate hosting:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Domains with leading `www` will not be affected by this. You can include such domains by using: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/?(?:www\.)?domain1.com`

Comment: Can you explain why this doesn't work when the final domain is "https" and one of the domains is the same name eg `bob.com` and the final rule is `https://www.bob.com` - it returns a mis-configuration error

Comment: And how can I handle it if somebody is calling one of my domains with https? E.g. https://domain1.com.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of redirecting `a.com`, `b.com`, `c.com` to `newdomain.com` you can do this:

Redirect everything that is **not** `newdomain.com` to `http://www.newdomain.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Credit for this goes to: http://www.raramuridesign.com/blog/83-dev-htaccess-redirect-a-domain-or-multiple-domains.html where it is explained in greater detail.

I tried it out for a client project and it works like a charm.

Comment: ì guess that if i complete the `RewriteCond` address to `www.newdomain.com`, it's gonna also redirect any subdomain to www. am i right?

Comment: This works great, except when there's something appended to the url (e.g. example.com/members). Is it possible to expand it to automatically include latter parts of the entered URL?

Comment: this does not solve the problem. if i have test.com/one and so on up to test.com/ten, and i want only the latter 5 to be redirected to newtest.com/ , this won't do

Answer (score 2):

My experience after few days rummaging SO and other hosts instructions was disappointing. However, I cherry-picked the best workful parts of all of them and yields the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain3\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

- The above format is also according to cPanel style of redirection done in GUI.
- Redirection of www. version and non-www. version of domains is one of the issues which other solutions **(at least I tried em!)** couldn't solve it.
- Pay attention to `^/?$` in `RewriteRule`

If you want to redirect www version of the main domain to the **non-www version** of it, the last two lines should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Good Redirection!

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The `^domain.com` solves the problem of the WWW, so all sub domains will now redirect.

Make sure that `http://www.newdomain.com` is not included in the `RewriteCond`.

That would cause a redirect loop

[More info](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html)

Comment: Is it possible to match "anything that is *not* newdomain.com" instead of manually adding each domain as a `RewriteCond`? This would be a huge hassle for me to do because there are about 18 domains that point to the new one, and the customer is considering adding more soon (and i don't want to have to dig in the .htaccess every time).

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^newdomain.com` I think this could work

Comment: That doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I guess i'll have to do it manually for each domain. I assume i can just add multiple `RewriteCond` lines and it'll work?