# Redirecting to 404 page error in php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how to redirect old url page to new pages by editing .htaccess file:

old links:-
`http://www.ssttechnology.com/seoservices.php
http://www.ssttechnology.com/softwareservices.php
http://www.ssttechnology.com/webservices.php`

redirect to new links:-
`http://www.ssttechnology.com/seo-services.php
http://www.ssttechnology.com/software-services.php
http://www.ssttechnology.com/web-services.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365397/redirect-multiple-domains-to-one-domain-with-or-without-www-before

Comment: Do you want to use PHP or Apache to redirect? Do you just want to do redirects or do you want to redirect to an error page and send a 404 error? Your question title doesn't seem to match your question.